# get value of image url using htm2canvas

Tags: html, html2canvas

to get an image of my div I used html2canvas, the problem is that, when I use the variable that contains my url it gives my "undefined".How can I solve it.
Here is my code:

```
var url;
html2canvas($("#mydiv"), {
                        onrendered: function(canvas) {         
                        url= canvas.toDataURL();              
                            }}
console.log(url);
```